# convergent series with unbounded terms?

Tags: analysis

Are there any sequences $\{a_n\}$ such that $\sum_n a_n <\infty$ but $\{a_n\}$ is unbounded?

I want to say there aren't any but I can't think of any counterexamples. Just want to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sum a_n<\infty$, then $a_n\to 0$. That is, there exists an $N$ such that $|a_n|<1$ whenever $n>N$. It follows that $\{|a_n|\}$ is bounded by
$$
M=\max\{|a_1|,\dotsc,|a_N|,1\}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\;,\;\;\text{so}\;\;\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k<\infty\iff \lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=S<\infty\implies a_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$